# Apple MDM Certificate Signature Verification failed because the signature is invalid

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am getting Certificate Signature Verification failed error. The description is, Certificate Signature Verification failed because the signature is invalid. The CSR used to work fine until now. I recently updated my MDM Certificate, does it have anything to do with that change?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I updated my MDM Certificate and the signing certificate was using old MDM Certificate. I had to change the signing certificate to reflect the new MDM certificate